# Como parar el proceso php antes de que llegue a la base de datos?

Tags: php, mysqli

Tengo este fragmento de código:

```
$clientes = mysqli_query($conexion2,"SELECT * FROM cliente");
        while($consulta = mysqli_fetch_assoc($clientes)){
            if ($email==$consulta['Email']) {
                ?>
                    <script>
                    alert('Error: CORREO YA EXISTENTE, favor de utilizar utilizar otro.');
                            location.href='crearCuenta.php';
                    </script>
                <?php 
            }
        }

        $statement = $conexion->prepare(
            "INSERT INTO cliente (idcliente, Nombre, ApellidoPaterno, ApellidoMaterno, Email, Tel, pass, idRol)
            VALUES (null, :nombre, :apellidop, :apellidom, :email, :tel, :pass, '2')"
        );
```

Lo que quiero es que si pasa por el if, antes de que cierren los corchetes acabe el proceso y ya no continúe, por que cuando pasa por el if me cambia la direccion por el `location` pero todavía guarda los datos en BD.

Como le hago para que cuando pasa por el if, no me mande los datos a la BD?

Intente poner un `else` pero como hay un while, hace muchos `insert into`

Comment: Intentaste colocando un `break;`?

Comment: uso mysqli, y si utilize un break. pero cuando el correo si es valido, como esta cortado, no lo registra

Comment: @Bicho ........

Comment: Busca el correo en el `select` directamente.

Answer (score 1):

Comentarios:

- Para verificar si ya existe un registro coincidente con base en el *email* sería mas conveniente realizarlo así:

  ```
  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cliente WHERE email = "aqui el valor";
  ```
- Tomando el valor calculado nos apoyamos de [*`bind_result`*](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php) para vincularlo a una variable.
- Con lo anterior evitarías entonces:

  - Seleccionar todos los registros de tu tabla
  - Tener que iterar todos los registros obtenidos para posterior tener que evaluar mediante un *if*
- Es importante hacer notar que en *mysqli* se usan [marcadores de parámetro](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.prepare.php), por ende deberás:

  - Pasar de esto: *`:nombre`*
  - A esto: *`?`* y así por cada valor que llegue a la query de manera dinámica

Tu código sería entonces:

```
$queryVerificadora = $conexion2->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cliente WHERE email = ?");
$queryVerificadora->bind_param("s", $email);
$queryVerificadora->execute();

$queryVerificadora->bind_result($conteoTotal);

$queryVerificadora->fetch();

if ($conteoTotal === 0) {

    $statement = $conexion2->prepare("INSERT INTO cliente (idcliente, Nombre, ApellidoPaterno, ApellidoMaterno, Email, Tel, pass, idRol) VALUES (null, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, '2')");
    ......................................   

} else {

    /*
        Aquí la redirección para que cree la cuenta
    */

}
```

Comment: Solo como nota en este caso en la consulta para saber si existe un el email sería más adecuado utilizar `SELECT email FROM cliente WHERE email = ? LIMIT 1` ya que evitamos crear una columna calculada y con el `LIMIT 1` evitamos escanear toda la tabla en mysql, aún que dejemos el count en este tipo de consultas es importante añadir el LIMIT 1. También en lugar del else si se quiere cortar la ejecución podríamos utilizar exit o excepciones.